# Cannot run Xpath queries from JAVA in XML files having <DOCTYPE> tag

Tags: java, xml, dtd, xml-parsing

I have made the following method which runs hard-coded xPath queries in a hard-coded XML file. The method works perfect with one exception. Some xml files contains the following tag

```
           <!DOCTYPE WorkFlowDefinition SYSTEM "wfdef4.dtd">
```

When i try to run a query in that file i get the following exception:

```
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
     C:\ProgramFiles\code\other\xPath\wfdef4.dtd(The system cannot find the file specified).
```

The question is  : **What can i do to instruct my program not to take under consideration this DTD file?**
I have also noted that the path C:\ProgramFiles\code\other\xPath\wfdef4.dtd is the one i run my application from and not the one that the actual xml file is located.

Thank you in advace

Here is my method:

```
 public String evaluate(String expression,File file){
  XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
  StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
  try{
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file));
                         //evaluates the expression
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate(expression, 
                   inputSource,XPathConstants.NODESET);

                         //does other stuff, irrelevant with my question.
    for (int i = 0 ; i <nodeList.getLength(); i++){
     strBuffer.append(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
    }
  }catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return strBuffer.toString();
      }
```

Comment: This is a similar case, You might find it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243728/how-to-disable-dtd-at-runtime-in-javas-xpath

Comment: As suggest by @adrianboimvaser, this has nothing to do with XPath, but XML parser. Conceptually is a duplicate of   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references

Comment: @aAlejandro. In my case i do not use any documentBuilderFactory, but even if i did , i cannot see a way to use the xPath.evaluate with it

Comment: @abrianboimvaser Thanks for replying. As i mentioned above i dont know how to use both DocumentBuilderFactory and Xpath. Also in the case you referred to the override method you have to know which DTD you have. In my case the DTD is different (i have not mentioned that )

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726279/parsing-an-xml-file-with-a-dtd-schema-on-a-relative-path/57823304#57823304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is :

```
    xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    //add this line to ignore dth DTD
    dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```