# Cannot read XMLFile with exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Temp\logger.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, xml, logging

I am having trouble reading an XMLfile that is created by the class below. I am led to believe there is some property here that I need to set in order for the correct file directory to be used. The XMLfile that is generated with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
```

at the top can be read if I remove the line containing "logger.dtd" . Can someone explain what is going on? I am reading from the same URI that I set using the SAXParser API. I followed the instructions for SAX parsing here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

```
    package logging;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
    import java.util.logging.Handler;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
    import java.util.logging.XMLFormatter;

    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

    public class Log {
static private FileHandler fileTxt;
static private SimpleFormatter formatterTxt;
static private FileHandler fileXML;
static private XMLFormatter formatterXML;



static public void setup(Logger theLogger) throws IOException{
    Logger logger = theLogger;

    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

    fileTxt = new FileHandler("C:\\Temp\\logging.txt");
    fileXML = new FileHandler("C:\\Temp\\XMLLogging.xml");

    formatterTxt = new SimpleFormatter();
    fileTxt.setFormatter(formatterTxt);
    logger.addHandler(fileTxt);

    formatterXML = new XMLFormatter();
    fileXML.setFormatter(formatterXML);
    logger.addHandler(fileXML);

    for(Handler h: logger.getHandlers()){
        System.out.println(h.getFormatter());
    }


}

}
```

Comment: You should have logger.dtd file located in the same directory as XMLLogging.xml. You can read more about dtd [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition).

Comment: So that is something I generate myself in eclipse? Is there no automated process that goes along with the logging api in java?

Comment: If you can acquire DTD from the same source as your XMLLogging.xml that would be the best way. If that's not possible, there are a lot of DTD generators online, and you can generate with [Eclipse XML Editor](http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/) as well.

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726279/parsing-an-xml-file-with-a-dtd-schema-on-a-relative-path/57823304#57823304

Answer (score 0):

although its been sometime for this question, however, i ran into this situation and had to struggle for a solution. i found this, may be if it works for others as well

```
@Override
public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
 if (systemId.contains("log4j.dtd")) {
  return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
 } else {
  return null;
 }
}
```

implement this method and mention you dtd name and it should proceed without any exception.

Answer (score -1):

> ...at the top can be read if I remove the line containing "logger.dtd" . Can someone explain what is going on?

The error is thrown because the SAX parser defaults to validating and loading external DTD.  If you don't want it to do that then disable the validation:

```
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
```

SAX will no longer look for the DTD file and will not throw the file not found exception.

Otherwise, the "logger.dtd" file can be found in the [Java Logging Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a3.0) under **3.0 Appendix A: DTD for XMLFormatter Output**.

```
<!-- DTD used by the java.util.logging.XMLFormatter -->
<!-- This provides an XML formatted log message. -->

<!-- The document type is "log" which consists of a sequence
of record elements -->
<!ELEMENT log (record*)>

<!-- Each logging call is described by a record element. -->
<!ELEMENT record (date, millis, sequence, logger?, level,
class?, method?, thread?, message, key?, catalog?, param*, exception?)>

<!-- Date and time when LogRecord was created in ISO 8601 format -->
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>

<!-- Time when LogRecord was created in milliseconds since
midnight January 1st, 1970, UTC. -->
<!ELEMENT millis (#PCDATA)>

<!-- Unique sequence number within source VM. -->
<!ELEMENT sequence (#PCDATA)>

<!-- Name of source Logger object. -->
<!ELEMENT logger (#PCDATA)>

<!-- Logging level, may be either one of the constant
names from java.util.logging.Level (such as "SEVERE"
or "WARNING") or an integer value such as "20". -->
<!ELEMENT level (#PCDATA)>

<!-- Fully qualified name of class that issued
logging call, e.g. "javax.marsupial.Wombat". -->
<!ELEMENT class (#PCDATA)>

<!-- Name of method that issued logging call.
It may be either an unqualified method name such as
"fred" or it may include argument type information
in parenthesis, for example "fred(int,String)". -->
<!ELEMENT method (#PCDATA)>

<!-- Integer thread ID. -->
<!ELEMENT thread (#PCDATA)>

<!-- The message element contains the text string of a log message. -->
<!ELEMENT message (#PCDATA)>

<!-- If the message string was localized, the key element provides
the original localization message key. -->
<!ELEMENT key (#PCDATA)>

<!-- If the message string was localized, the catalog element provides
the logger's localization resource bundle name. -->
<!ELEMENT catalog (#PCDATA)>

<!-- If the message string was localized, each of the param elements
provides the String value (obtained using Object.toString())
of the corresponding LogRecord parameter. -->
<!ELEMENT param (#PCDATA)>

<!-- An exception consists of an optional message string followed
by a series of StackFrames. Exception elements are used
for Java exceptions and other java Throwables. -->
<!ELEMENT exception (message?, frame+)>

<!-- A frame describes one line in a Throwable backtrace. -->
<!ELEMENT frame (class, method, line?)>

<!-- an integer line number within a class's source file. -->
<!ELEMENT line (#PCDATA)>
```

You have to just copy the text and place it into a file named "logger.dtd" and place it in the same directory as your xml log files.  Then the SAX parser will be able to find file because it exists.

You can also find links to this by searching the [logging package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).