# Parsing an XML file with a relative DTD without specifying its path explicitly

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I have run into the same problem [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726279/parsing-an-xml-file-with-a-dtd-schema-on-a-relative-path): I want to parse a XML file that contains a relative path to a DTD file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE convert SYSTEM "someRules.dtd">
```

In the linked question there is an answer that works. However it specifies the name and path explicit like this:

```
db.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
            throws SAXException, IOException {
        if (systemId.contains("schema.dtd")) {
            return new InputSource(new FileReader("/path/to/schema.dtd"));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

I want not to write `schema.dtd` and `/path/to/schema.dtd` explicit but rather fetch it the XML file (in my case this would be `someRules.dtd`) and then dynamically search for it in the path specified in the XML document.
This avoids having to change my java code when I decide to change the location of `someRules.dtd` later. I want to only have to move `someRules.dtd` and adjust its path in the XML document.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify an absolute path to any DTD in your xml.

If you really need to do so (for testing purposes), the entire path will be stored in the systemId String of your resolveEntity function.

```
if(systemId.endsWith(".dtd")){
        return new InputSource(new FileReader(systemId));
}
```

This should work as long as the dtd is available on your machine, but it's terrible design.

You should be looking at DTD catalog files as an alternative solution